# SQL transaction: Delete between two selects possible?

Tags: locking, transaction, data-synchronization

I have two SELECT statements within a transaction (repeatable read)

```
Select @firstItem =id from myTable Where ....
```

--Do some more magic, so I can't concat the the two queries!!!!

and

```
Select * from myTable where parent=@firstItem
```

Is it possible that the children (second query) of the parent(first query) are deleted (from another transaction) after the initial/first select?

How can I prevent this with locks?

Comment: Do you have a particular database management system (e.g. PostgreSQL, DB2, SQL Server, MySQL) in mind? Please add the corresponding tag(s) if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible that the children (second query) of the parent(first
>   query) are deleted (from another transaction) after the initial/first
>   select?

Certainly it is possible.

When you execute your `first query` only the result row of the first query has `S-lock` (I suppose your table has an index on id).

If you want to `lock` the rows where this id is a parent, you should just do this select in the same query:

```
select * 
from myTable 
where parent = (
    select id 
    from myTable 
    where ...);
```

This way you `lock` that `id` and all the rows where `parent = this id` so they cannot be deleted.

Note that only these rows are locked because your TIL is `repeatable read`, this means that if during the duration of this transaction other rows with this parent are `inserted` they can also be `deleted`.

To prevent insertions/deletions of the **new** rows with this parent you should use `serializable` TIL.

---

Here is my repro:
The first session(56) creates the table and fills it with id 1..10000
and then adds random parents from the same range 1..10000.

Then I search for most "popular" parent with max count of corrensonding childs,
and in session 54 I try to delete one of the child, the query is blocked.

The "central" window shows you the locks held, I used it twice: first to see what my first session locks, second time to see what the second session is waiting for. First session has 1+ 6 locks 1 on parent row and 6 on child rows that you see in the output of the first query, the second session waits on conversion from update lock to exclusive lock on the row it wanted to delete.
The session is "hanging" until rollback or commit.

Here is the picture:

[image]

```
if object_id('myTable') is not null drop table myTable;
create table myTable(id int identity not null primary key clustered, 
                     parent int, 
                     col varchar(10) not null);

alter table myTable 
add constraint FK_paerent_id foreign key (parent) references myTable(id);

alter table myTable add constraint UQ_myTable_col unique(col);

create index ix_parent on myTable(parent);

insert into myTable with(tablock) (col) 
select top 10000 cast(row_number() over(order by getdate()) as varchar(10)) as col
from sys.columns c1 cross join sys.columns c2;

update myTable
set parent = abs(checksum(newid())) % 10000 + 1;

select parent,
       count(*) as cnt
from myTable 
group by parent
having count(*) > 1
order by cnt desc;

set transaction isolation level repeatable read;

begin tran

select id 
from myTable 
where parent = (
    select id 
    from myTable 
    where col = '481');

--rollback
```

Comment: Two questions: 1.) Are you sure this will work? As far as I know even concatenated queries aren't executed atomic (at least no guarantee) 2.) How to solve the problem WITHOUT concatenating the query?

Comment: 1. It's simple to reproduce I'll update my answer with small repro in some minutes. 2. If the only mode to describe your condition is to execute both queries, the answer is there is no other way (you certainly can lock your table exclusively with tablockx but this is not a good solution)